# login button not working after permission to acces files granted in android app

Tags: android, android-permissions

This problem only exist during the first run of app after installation , that the login button not working after permission to access files granted ,in the next app run the login button works perfectly.  can any one please tell me what is the issue associated with this.

Providing code for login activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=24){
        try{
            Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
            m.invoke(null);
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }



    int hasWriteContactsPermissionW = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(login.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
    if (hasWriteContactsPermissionW != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(login.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
            showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Files", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(login.this, new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE}, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
                }
            });

            return;
        }
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(login.this,
                new String[] {Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

        return;
    }

    loginbtn = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);

    loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Log.d("MMMMMM", "CLICKEDDD");

            loginbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            EditText emailtxt = findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);
            String email = emailtxt.getText().toString();

            EditText passtxt = findViewById(R.id.passwordtxt);
            String pass = passtxt.getText().toString();


            GlobalVar.hash = String.valueOf(hashing.md5encrypt(email + pass));

            Connect();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code does not run at first. It is because the permission checker stops execution when permission is granted on first run. I've copied your code snippet and commented the line

```
if (hasWriteContactsPermissionW != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    if(.....) {
        // .... your code 
    }

    return; // this statement terminates (stops ?) the function
    // solution is to remove this line 
}

// these lines are never reached because of the return; above
loginbtn = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
```

**Solution :**

1. Check permissions at the end of `onCreate`
2. Remove `return;` from block where you check permissions

**Modified Code :**

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
 super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
 setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

 if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 24) {
  try {
   Method m = StrictMode.class.getMethod("disableDeathOnFileUriExposure");
   m.invoke(null);
  } catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
  }
 }

 // moved this above
 loginbtn = findViewById(R.id.loginbtn);
 loginbtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

   Log.d("MMMMMM", "CLICKEDDD");

   loginbtn.setVisibility(View.GONE);

   EditText emailtxt = findViewById(R.id.emailtxt);
   String email = emailtxt.getText().toString();

   EditText passtxt = findViewById(R.id.passwordtxt);
   String pass = passtxt.getText().toString();


   GlobalVar.hash = String.valueOf(hashing.md5encrypt(email + pass));

   Connect();
  }
 });

 // moved this below
 int hasWriteContactsPermissionW = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(login.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
 if (hasWriteContactsPermissionW != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
  if (!ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(login.this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)) {
   showMessageOKCancel("You need to allow access to Files", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(login.this, new String[] {
      Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
     }, REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);
    }
   });

   return;
  }
  ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(login.this,
   new String[] {
    Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
   },
   REQUEST_CODE_ASK_PERMISSIONS);

  return;
 }

}
```